# Can't download iOS 7.1 Simulator on Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6.4

Is it possible to download iOS 7.1 Simulator on Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan, I see strange error:

> Could not download and install iOS 7.1 Simulator. The request timed
>   out. Network Diagnostics can help you solve network connection
>   problems.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The iOS 7.1 Simulator runtime is not supported on OS X El Capitan.  It should not even be presented as an option.